# how to form a sentence. find below example

Tags: word-usage, word-order

1. please find **the below** work status.
2. Please find **below the** work status

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see people new to English make this mistake all the time on this forum. They for some unknown to me reason wrongly assume that ***below*** is somehow an adjective, but that's actually completely wrong. Just look it up in any online dictionary and you will see that ***below*** can either be a preposition or an adverb and it's typically never the case when it can be used as an adjective. So, as is common for most adverbs of place (there might be exceptions though), the placement of ***below*** should go somewhere near the end of your sentence:

> Please find the work status **below**.

What you are trying to find is the work status and the question that one can ask is where are you trying to find it? The answer would be somewhere below at a lower level with respect to some implicit point of reference. That's what makes it an adverb of place.

Some might argue that the word ***below*** in your example is a preposition. By no means am I an expert in English grammar, but, to the best of my knowledge, prepositions take objects while adverbs stand on their own and work only in conjunction with verbs. In our example here, ***below*** does not precede anything. So, it must be an adverb.

PS: In conversational English, **please find the below work status** would probably work fine too. **please find below the work status** does sound strange, however.